# How can I get the name of the file to be uploaded by primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I am using the "FileUpload" component of primefaces with "advanced" mode, and I want to get the name of the file once the user makes his choice of the file that he wants to upload and before submitting.

Attributes "Onstart" AND "Oncomplete" are executed after clicking the submit button, so I can not use them.

I tried also getting the name using a validator methode, but It seems to be a primefaces bug, because the method is never invocked.

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileToUpload" label="Browse"
                            fileUploadListener="#{uploadFile.handleFileUpload}"
                            mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" value = "#{uploadFile.file2}"
                            update="growl uploadFile_exposureType"
                            oncomplete="if(PF('ajaxLoaderDialogWidgetImport')) PF('ajaxLoaderDialogWidgetImport').hide();refreshAllRowNumbers();PF('importRisksList').hide();"
                            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xlsx|xls|kml)$/"
                            onstart="if(PF('ajaxLoaderDialogWidgetImport')) PF('ajaxLoaderDialogWidgetImport').show();"
                            styleClass="reimport_upload Browse browse_uploadBtn" valueChangeListener="#{uploadFile.handleChange}" >
                            </p:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set fileUploadLisener(fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" ).

In bean gets the filename using

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    fileName = event.getFile().getFileName();
}
```